# Read another line from an input file in c++

Tags: c++, input, output

So I am trying to read from an input file and translate that data onto an output file with a bar chart. I can open and read the input file but I get stuck in the loop because I don't know how to move on to the next line for the other set of data in the input file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   ifstream inFile;
   ofstream outFile;
   unsigned int storeNum;
   long long int salesData;
   string fileName;

   cout << "Please enter file name: ";
   cin >> fileName;

   inFile.open(fileName);
   if (inFile) {
      while (inFile >> storeNum >> salesData, '\n')
      {
         if (storeNum < 1 || storeNum > 99)
         {
            cout << "The store number " << storeNum << setw(2) << "is not valid" << endl;
         }
         if (salesData < 0)
         {
            cout << "The sales value for store " << storeNum << setw(2) << " is negative" << endl;
         }
         else {
         outFile.open("saleschart.txt");
         outFile << "SALES BAR CHART" << endl;
         outFile << "(Each X equals 1,000 dollars)" << endl;
         while (storeNum > 0)
         { 
            outFile << "Store " << storeNum << setw(2) << ": ";
            while (salesData > 1000)
            { 
               outFile << "X";
               salesData = salesData - 1000;
            }
            outFile << endl;
         }
         }


      }
      inFile.close();
   }

   else
   {
      cout << "File " << fileName << " could not be opened" << endl;
   }

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To read a file line by line, use `std::getline`:

```
std::string text_line;
while (std::getline(inFile, text_line))
{
//...
}
```

To extract numbers from a string, use `std::istringstream`:

```
std::istringstream text_stream(text_line);
text_stream >> storeNum >> salesData;
```

Also, search the internet for "c++ read file space separated" or "c++ read file CSV".